# ASP.NET Button with Bootstrap Glyphicon

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I'm attempting to use glyphicons as icons for ASP `Button`.

I know you can easily do this by giving the `<i>` element the proper `glyphicon` CSS, and then parent it under the desired button.

However, I want to do this from the C# side NOT HTML. How do I do this?

I tried the following, to no avail:

```
HtmlGenericControl i1 = new HtmlGenericControl("i");
i1.Attributes["class"] = "glyphicon glyphicon-backward";
i1.Attributes["aria-hidden"] = "true";

Button btnFirst = new Button();
btnFirst.ID = "btnFirst";
btnFirst.CommandName = "FirstPage";
btnFirst.CssClass = "btn btn-default pageButton";
btnFirst.Click += new EventHandler(btnFirst_Click);
btnFirst.Controls.Add(i1);
container.Controls.Add(btnFirst);
```

If I run this as above, the button is shown, but there is no icon. 
In the HTML, there is no `<i>` element nested beneath the button. In fact, it appears to no exist.

Comment: Do you have all the correct setup in your CSS? Could you include any CSS you are using that would be relevant to this? Also, what are you trying to do with making the `i` tag a child control of your `Button` control? The output of that would probably be something like `<button><i/></button>`...

Comment: what HTML output do you end up with using the above?

Comment: Whats "i"? Use button tag, then apply the class for it.

Comment: I added more information above!
I'm basically trying to have it look like this:
`<button><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward"></i></button>`
I cannot simply apply the glyphicon class to the button itself, as that does nothing.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically you cannot use `<asp:Button>` with glyphicons because `<asp:Button>` turns into `<input type='button'>` that does not support any child elements.

**Two possible solutions:**

---

Use `<asp:LinkButton>` instead of `<asp:Button>`:

```
<asp:LinkButton runat="server" ID="lbFoo" OnClick="lbFoo_Click" CssClass="btn btn-default">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>Back
</asp:LinkButton>
```

This is the common solution.

---

Or use `<button>` to submit a hidden `<asp:Button>`

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" onclick="<%=btnHidden.ClientID %>.click()">
    <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-backward" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    Click
</button>

<asp:Button runat="server" style="display:none;" ID="btnHidden"
    OnClick="btnHidden_Click"></asp:Button>
```

This is a workaround if you insist using `<asp:Button>` and not `<asp:LinkButton>`. There are some other workarounds but this is the most legit.